# How can i use a C++ code and add it to a C# gui button

Tags: c#, c++

This is my first post.. I don't really now how to work this overflow as well so I will just see what I can do. As i tried to understand it around here.. (i am very new to this) I can't get a grip on it... So my code is simple a with sendinput and now I have to combine that to a C# GUI.. I just don't know how.. can someone help me my code is..

```
int main()
{
    ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    Sleep(2000);
    INPUT ip = {};

    ip.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    ip.mi.dx = 3500;
    ip.mi.dy = 2300;
    ip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    ip.mi.mouseData = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    Sleep(200);

    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wVk = 0x4B;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x49;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x53;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x53;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x41;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x4E;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x49;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x4D;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x45;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x6E;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x52;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x55;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.wVk = 0x0D;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this _C++_ code an application or library? Judging by `Main()` it's an application.

Comment: its a application, but it should be a DLL i suppose, for now its a application, which i want to combine with a C# Gui, to be honest, i have no idea where i have to start... or even what to do. Hence i am asking here

Comment: IT depends on your needs. Applications are good to create _pipelines_ and libraries to create simple calls.

Comment: Hmm i really can't say.. i have tried to make it into a DLL for wrapping to a C#... but the issue is what i have to do.. i am really new to this so. This code was just a task i had to make.. which later they said.. now bind it to a C# gui.. and that's where i truly got lost... i don't know what i have to do from that point on...

Comment: i wish someone can show me how i can put this into something as i stated, that if i press on a C# button that the code above will occurs

Comment: Try compile your code above as dll, with /clr, make the method public and just add this dll as reference in C#.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jeScuwK9

Comment: hmmm i will try this also ~ thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a native C++ code with C# use PInvoke check this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx

and in the C++ Code you can put your code inside a function and export it, this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx
, then build your C++ and use the native dll with your C# project.

Comment: I also suggest peeking at the pinvoke.net interop wiki's documentation on [`SendInput`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html) and [`struct INPUT`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/INPUT.html).

Comment: so.. wait.. with pinvoke i only need one file?? instead of like.. 3? basically i put my C++ code into the C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so first you have to find out your requirements. Do you want to make a *pipeline* from few applications or do you prefer to make simple calls.

To make something like *pipeline* you have to consider "naming" your exit codes.
eg.

```
0 == Everything went okay,
1 == There was an error with ...
2 == Uncaught exception ...
```

Then in your *C++* application use these codes :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    BOOL no_errors = TRUE;
    try
    {
        ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

        Sleep(2000);
        INPUT ip = {};

        ip.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        ip.mi.dx = 3500;
        ip.mi.dy = 2300;
        ip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        ip.mi.mouseData = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        Sleep(200);

        ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ip.ki.wVk = 0x4B;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x49;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x53;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x53;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x41;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x4E;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x49;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x4D;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x45;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x6E;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x52;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x55;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x0D;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        no_errors = FALSE;
    }
    if(no_errors)
        return 0; // look error code at position 0
    else
        return 1; // look error code at position 1
}
```

When you complete recoding your *C++* application you can just start it up using `Process` class within *C#* :

```
Process proc = Process.Start("me_cpp_application.exe");
proc.WaitForExit();
int result = proc.ExitCode;
// result now holds your error/exit code
```

Another way to do this is to make calls to native code using *platform invoke*.
This will require from you to modify your *C++* code into library instead of application.

```
// c++ code :
#ifdef ME_LIB
#    define LIB_SPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define LIB_SPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define EXPORT_DLL extern "C" LIB_SPEC 

EXPORT_DLL  int MyCall() {
    BOOL no_errors = TRUE;
    try
    {
        ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

        Sleep(2000);
        INPUT ip = {};

        ip.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        ip.mi.dx = 3500;
        ip.mi.dy = 2300;
        ip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        ip.mi.mouseData = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        Sleep(200);

        ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ip.ki.wVk = 0x4B;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x49;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x53;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x53;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x41;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x4E;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x49;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x4D;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x45;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x6E;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x52;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x55;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.wVk = 0x0D;
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        no_errors = FALSE;
    }
    if (no_errors)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

And then in your *C#* application just use:

```
[DllImport("me_cpp_library.dll")]
static extern int MyCall();

void CallMyCallNative()
{
    int result = MyCall();
}
```

Comment: hmm as well thanks in advance~ i will try this as well

Comment: hmm maybe this will be to much to ask... but can you show me it with my code? perhaps

Comment: hmmm thanks <3 only one more question... you said modify it into a library. do you mean i have to make a lib file instead? or a dll? or just use my application ? like in visual studio? once more.. thank you very much~

Comment: @illyasviel library means you have to compile into `.DLL` file.

Comment: IT WORKS THANK YOU <3 <3 <3 < 3 :D <3 < 3 <3